# Bootstrap Button Collapse to second line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am wondering if there is a way to get the buttons to automatically grow vertically to display the entire label rather then cut it off using bootstrap and font awesome.

Code:

```
<div class="well well-sm"> 
    <p><h5 style="underline"><u>Social Media:</u></h5></p>
    <p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <font size="2"> Like us on Facebook</font>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-twitter" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> <font size="2"> Follow us on Twitter</font>
    </a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-pinterest" target="_blank">
        <span class="fa fa-youtube-play"></span> <font size="2"> Watch us on YouTube</font>
    </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Current Output:

____Small screen_____________large screen

[image]

... large screen is good but i want the small screen buttons to have output like:

Like us on   <-first line

facebook     <-second line

Comment: Add `a { word-wrap: break-word; }` to your CSS

Comment: Try `white-space: normal;` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, the answer above(by Ryan) would work `word-wrap: break-word;` but some highlights about Bootstrap.

Bootstrap tend to have some hidden CSS.

Especially the one: `overflow: hidden;` which sometimes doesn't make work-wrap work!

Lastly, Try to `inspect` the website in order to see what exactly is happening to you code.

Hope this address your issue!